# ubuntu freeze do i need more ram?

Tags: 18.04, hardware, ram, hardware-acceleration

I am currently running a dual boot setup for ubuntu 18.04 and windows 10. While building some code on ubuntu(along with several internet tabs opened), my computer will freeze and lag to the point i need to do something like make -j1 and close tabs for it to work. It is getting annoying. Is my bottleneck simply a lack of memory? Can i do anything else other than upgrading my ram? This is what my system process looks like when my computer froze
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YTJG.jpg)

this is how my lshw looks like

```
inspiron-5482
    description: Convertible
    product: Inspiron 5482 (089E)
    vendor: Dell Inc.
    serial: 8ZFY2P2
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.2 dmi-3.2 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=convertible family=Inspiron sku=089E uuid=44454C4C-5A00-1046-8059-B8C04F325032
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 0CVXN6
       vendor: Dell Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: A00
       serial: /8ZFY2P2/CNWSC008BF000H/
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Dell Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: 2.9.0
          date: 12/28/2020
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 15MiB
          capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot uefi
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 29
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 8GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2667 MHz (0.4 ns)
             product: HMA81GS6CJR8N-VK
             vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
             physical id: 0
             serial: 2D84F6B4
             slot: DIMM A
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 2667MHz (0.4ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: [empty]
             physical id: 1
             slot: DIMM B
     *-cache:0
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 32
          slot: L1 Cache
          size: 256KiB
          capacity: 256KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=1
     *-cache:1
          description: L2 cache
          physical id: 33
          slot: L2 Cache
          size: 1MiB
          capacity: 1MiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=2
     *-cache:2
          description: L3 cache
          physical id: 34
          slot: L3 Cache
          size: 6MiB
          capacity: 6MiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=3
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8265U CPU @ 1.60GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 35
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8265U CPU @ 1.60GHz
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: U3E1
          size: 3824MHz
          capacity: 3900MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=8
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Intel Corporation
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 0b
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=skl_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:161 memory:a4000000-a4ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-generic:0
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
             version: 0b
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm cap_list
             configuration: driver=proc_thermal latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:a5210000-a5217fff
        *-generic:1 UNCLAIMED
             description: System peripheral
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 8
             bus info: pci@0000:00:08.0
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:a522e000-a522efff
        *-generic:2
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 12
             bus info: pci@0000:00:12.0
             version: 30
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel_pch_thermal latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:a522d000-a522dfff
        *-communication:0
             description: Serial controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 13
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.0
             version: 30
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm 8250 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel_ish_ipc latency=0
             resources: irq:20 memory:a5224000-a5225fff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 30
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:126 memory:a5200000-a520ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.4.0-74-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 5.04
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=12 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Keyboard
                   product: Gaming KB
                   vendor: SINO WEALTH
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 12.62
                   capabilities: usb-1.10
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=500mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Keyboard
                   product: Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1
                   vendor: Microsoft
                   physical id: 3
                   bus info: usb@1:3
                   version: 3.15
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:2 UNCLAIMED
                   description: Generic USB device
                   product: FingerPrint
                   vendor: Goodix
                   physical id: 5
                   bus info: usb@1:5
                   version: 1.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:3
                   description: Video
                   product: Integrated_Webcam_HD
                   vendor: CN0M1RXTLOG0087OC1K3A01
                   physical id: 6
                   bus info: usb@1:6
                   version: 85.02
                   capabilities: usb-2.01
                   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:4
                   description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: a
                   bus info: usb@1:a
                   version: 0.02
                   capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.4.0-74-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 5.04
                capabilities: usb-3.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=10000Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: Mass storage device
                   product: Ultra Fit
                   vendor: SanDisk
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: usb@2:2
                   logical name: scsi1
                   version: 1.00
                   serial: 4C530001050825111423
                   capabilities: usb-3.00 scsi emulated scsi-host
                   configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=896mA speed=5000Mbit/s
                 *-disk
                      description: SCSI Disk
                      product: Ultra Fit
                      vendor: SanDisk
                      physical id: 0.0.0
                      bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
                      logical name: /dev/sda
                      version: 1.00
                      serial: 4C530001050825111423
                      size: 28GiB (30GB)
                      capabilities: removable
                      configuration: ansiversion=6 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
                    *-medium
                         physical id: 0
                         logical name: /dev/sda
                         size: 28GiB (30GB)
                         capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
                       *-volume
                            description: Windows FAT volume
                            physical id: 1
                            logical name: /dev/sda1
                            logical name: /media/shane/CBB1-222B
                            version: FAT32
                            serial: cbb1-222b
                            size: 28GiB
                            capacity: 28GiB
                            capabilities: primary fat initialized
                            configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro state=mounted
        *-memory UNCLAIMED
             description: RAM memory
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
             version: 30
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
             capabilities: pm cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:a5222000-a5223fff memory:a522c000-a522cfff
        *-network
             description: Wireless interface
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
             logical name: wlo1
             version: 30
             serial: 18:1d:ea:1f:7f:84
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
             configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-74-generic firmware=46.6bf1df06.0 ip=192.168.0.106 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
             resources: irq:16 memory:a521c000-a521ffff
        *-serial:0
             description: Serial bus controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 15
             bus info: pci@0000:00:15.0
             version: 30
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel-lpss latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:7ec00000-7ec00fff
        *-serial:1
             description: Serial bus controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 15.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:15.1
             version: 30
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel-lpss latency=0
             resources: irq:17 memory:7ec01000-7ec01fff
        *-communication:1
             description: Communication controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 30
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:153 memory:a5229000-a5229fff
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 17
             bus info: pci@0000:00:17.0
             version: 30
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:127 memory:a5220000-a5221fff memory:a5228000-a52280ff ioport:4090(size=8) ioport:4080(size=4) ioport:4060(size=32) memory:a5227000-a52277ff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: f0
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:122
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.4
             version: f0
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:123 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:90000000-a30fffff
           *-display
                description: 3D controller
                product: GM108M [GeForce MX130]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                version: a2
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
                resources: irq:160 memory:a2000000-a2ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:a3000000-a307ffff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: f0
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:124 ioport:5000(size=4096) memory:7e800000-7e9fffff ioport:7ea00000(size=2097152)
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.4
             version: f0
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:125 memory:a5100000-a51fffff
           *-storage
                description: Non-Volatile memory controller
                product: Toshiba America Info Systems
                vendor: Toshiba America Info Systems
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                version: 01
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: storage pciexpress pm msi msix nvm_express bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=nvme latency=0
                resources: irq:16 memory:a5100000-a5103fff
              *-nvme0
                   description: NVMe device
                   product: KBG30ZMS256G NVMe TOSHIBA 256GB
                   physical id: 0
                   logical name: /dev/nvme0
                   version: ADDA0103
                   serial: 989PD0N3PWFP
                   configuration: nqn=nqn.2017-03.jp.co.toshiba:KBG30ZMS256G NVMe TOSHIBA 256GB:989PD0N3PWFP state=live
                 *-namespace
                      description: NVMe namespace
                      physical id: 1
                      logical name: /dev/nvme0n1
                      size: 238GiB (256GB)
                      capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
                      configuration: guid=6987e4e9-f4b3-4e66-a3e0-141975a6a22f logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
                    *-volume:0
                         description: Windows FAT volume
                         vendor: MSDOS5.0
                         physical id: 1
                         logical name: /dev/nvme0n1p1
                         version: FAT32
                         serial: de8c-66f8
                         size: 646MiB
                         capacity: 649MiB
                         capabilities: boot fat initialized
                         configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat label=ESP name=EFI system partition
                    *-volume:1
                         description: reserved partition
                         vendor: Windows
                         physical id: 2
                         logical name: /dev/nvme0n1p2
                         serial: a2f203e9-5e6f-433a-918c-1823dfd37c1b
                         capacity: 127MiB
                         capabilities: nofs
                         configuration: name=Microsoft reserved partition
                    *-volume:2
                         description: Windows FAT volume
                         vendor: -FVE-FS-
                         physical id: 3
                         logical name: /dev/nvme0n1p3
                         version: FAT32
                         serial: 0000-0000
                         size: 15EiB
                         capabilities: fat initialized
                         configuration: FATs=0 filesystem=fat name=Basic data partition
                    *-volume:3
                         description: Windows NTFS volume
                         vendor: Windows
                         physical id: 4
                         logical name: /dev/nvme0n1p4
                         version: 3.1
                         serial: c0b8-1046
                         size: 965MiB
                         capacity: 989MiB
                         capabilities: boot precious readonly hidden nomount ntfs initialized
                         configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2020-11-05 18:16:26 filesystem=ntfs modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
                    *-volume:4
                         description: Windows NTFS volume
                         vendor: Windows
                         physical id: 5
                         logical name: /dev/nvme0n1p5
                         version: 3.1
                         serial: aa1e-72ce
                         size: 13GiB
                         capacity: 13GiB
                         capabilities: boot precious readonly hidden nomount ntfs initialized
                         configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2018-11-18 07:20:24 filesystem=ntfs label=Image modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
                    *-volume:5
                         description: Windows NTFS volume
                         vendor: Windows
                         physical id: 6
                         logical name: /dev/nvme0n1p6
                         version: 3.1
                         serial: 583d-3637
                         size: 1087MiB
                         capacity: 1114MiB
                         capabilities: boot precious readonly hidden nomount ntfs initialized
                         configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2018-11-18 07:14:07 filesystem=ntfs label=DELLSUPPORT modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
                    *-volume:6
                         description: EXT4 volume
                         vendor: Linux
                         physical id: 7
                         logical name: /dev/nvme0n1p7
                         version: 1.0
                         serial: 2a618b4a-27a6-49e1-8d2f-f2cdaae37a33
                         size: 52GiB
                         capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                         configuration: created=2021-05-18 10:54:26 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2021-06-21 01:25:04 mounted=2021-06-20 17:25:04 state=clean
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 30
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 30
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
             resources: irq:162 memory:a5218000-a521bfff memory:a5000000-a50fffff
        *-serial:2 UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.4
             version: 30
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:a5226000-a52260ff ioport:efa0(size=32)
        *-serial:3 UNCLAIMED
             description: Serial bus controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.5
             version: 30
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:fe010000-fe010fff
  *-battery
       product: DELL CYMGM89
       vendor: Samsung SDI
       physical id: 1
       version: 09/24/2018
       serial: D485
       slot: Sys. Battery Bay
       capacity: 41990mWh
       configuration: voltage=11.4V
```

this is my swap space

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7643        2252        3537         517        1853        4607
Swap:          1392           0        1392
```

Comment: Your swap space is drastically tiny. You’ll want to bump that up to at least 8GB, and maybe a bit more.

Comment: @matigo when i first set up swap space, everyone has been telling me it doesn't need to be large.. but i will give it a try. does that mean my specs should be able to handle what i am doing?

Comment: I cannot answer the question about whether your computer can handle what you’re doing as I know little about your computer or what you’re doing. The i5 is certainly a good processor and Ubuntu is a solid OS, but if you’re compiling Skynet, then you might need a bit more power 

Comment: Yes, you would do better to have more RAM for what you're doing. More swap will just give it a little more time before it becomes sluggish again.

Comment: @popey yeah i tried increasing swap file size to 8GB but things are still kind of laggy. Might consider upgrading to 16GB ram, thanks.

Comment: If you have many tabs open in your browser, that's most likely what consumes most RAM. You can compensate to some extent with more swap, but that brings the machine to a screeching halt when you actually need it. First find out what actually fills your RAM, then make a decision how to proceed from there.

Comment: Having said that, more RAM is one of the best investments in hardware, right after using an SSD instead of a rotating hard disk.

Comment: @HuHa the thing is coming from Windows 10, i kind of feel the browser tabs is eating up more of my RAM in ubuntu than windows. i never really had this problem before on windows. so i thought there was something i needed to configure other than simply having to upgrade hardware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gotten a couple of solutions, one being increase swap space, another being increase RAM, and another is to optimise header dependencies by including headers in source files along with forward declarations(i code in c++).

The swap space problem reduces my computer from freezing up. After that it just slows down alot so the problem is kind of mitigated but not fully solved.

Next up, i tried to optimise header dependencies along with forward declarations and building time requires less RAM and takes less time.

At this point, i deemed the problem solved and did not resort to upgrading my RAM. If there are any other suggestions to smoothen things even more, do share.